# Is there a way to enforce that a class contains a specific Enum value (preferably inline)?

Tags: typescript, compiler-construction

I am working on a compiler in TypeScript at the moment and I have an Enum to represent Token Types and a class for the actual Token:

```js
enum TokenType {
    String,
    Integer,
    Float,
    Identifier,
    // ... elided
}

class Token {
    type: TokenType
    lexeme: string
    lineNo: number
    columnNo: number

    constructor(
        type: TokenType,
        lexeme: string,
        lineNo: number,
        columnNo: number
    ) {
        this.type = type
        this.lexeme = lexeme
        this.lineNo = lineNo
        this.columnNo = columnNo
    }

    toString(): string {
        return (
            'Token{' +
            [this.type, this.lexeme, this.lineNo, this.columnNo].join(',') +
            '}'
        )
    }
}
```

In my AST node's types I would like to specify that the Token hold a specific type, like for example in the `FunctionDeclaration` type:

```js
type FunctionDeclaration = {
    ident: Token with type = TokenType.identifier
    //           ^ Imaginary syntax, but this is what I'm trying to do
}
```

I've tried using `extend` like:

```js
interface IdentifierToken extends Token {
    type: TokenType.Identifier
}
```

However, this makes me cast a `new Token(TokenType.Identifier, ...)` as `IdentifierToken` even though the Token's type is `TokenType.Identifier`.

Also I would prefer to not have to declare new separate types for all the different TokenTypes (as there are ~25). So, would an inline way to enforce the values of class properties be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider making `Token` a [generic class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-classes) with a type parameter corresponding to the particular subtype of `TokenType` you are using:

```
class Token<T extends TokenType = TokenType> {
    type: T
    lexeme: string
    lineNo: number
    columnNo: number

    constructor(
        type: T,
        lexeme: string,
        lineNo: number,
        columnNo: number
    ) {
        this.type = type
        this.lexeme = lexeme
        this.lineNo = lineNo
        this.columnNo = columnNo
    }
}
```

Then you can easily refer to "a `Token` with a `type` equal to `XXX` as `Token<XXX>`:

```
type FunctionDeclaration = {
    ident: Token<TokenType.Identifier>
}
```

And additionally when you use the `Token` constructor, the compiler will infer `T` based on the construct parameters:

```
const identifierToken = new Token(TokenType.Identifier, "", 1, 2);
// const identifierToken: Token<TokenType.Identifier>

const f: FunctionDeclaration = { ident: identifierToken }; // okay

const floatToken = new Token(TokenType.Float, "", 3, 4);
// const floatToken: Token<TokenType.Float>

const g: FunctionDeclaration = { ident: floatToken }; // error!
// Type 'Token<TokenType.Float>' is not assignable to type 'Token<TokenType.Identifier>'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKg9ga1DAngB2FA3gKCvqAZQBcAnASxAHMAaPAgSRGOCuFLoKgDEAbOAIbFOjACahi5AGbl2I-AHoFUAHRqowXuXGicAXxw4AxrwEBnM7ESgAPDA0APFiFGX4SEKgxQAvFY9ewAB82PT4xOjAAFywYVC8wA7AENFQZmSUVHFaIMAAcnAx4BAARuxxRnC8kCAFRZBlpIZclSDppGBGxHCkABRxXBEYMTDyXPGJyantmWNcOfmFUMWNcwSV1RC1SyvlXACUoeMExAAW5GYqQ5h+1wMn55cJSSm+Ey-A9+GPKgsFb384F8oGcLioNjV-n4IVsCnEDHFuiQKNRevsYjNqEdjlBSMBiGBSCAoP0ceMAOTuUBYclQADUwK4AG1QZdrjQQT9nlMOazfpRFryfjDtgBdFQAKzglF65Jo5MODLJXHJenJwP28P0hmuPDAIC65DgIAAIsATAJSEIjcS-LguNoJCNrCA7C7AioGOJmNJZKQgtrjMb0lBHT6ZOwqbblsAAO7+UC9KMer0SX1yKAAIkzHIAjByAEz7ADcOCUUFaIbDkgjpCjzo8boCkU93prfoDQbaxCgUhi3H1huNZotVskxreWFDbZi1fTdZdUD0xag5cQAhQhkrPak-CEUbeuXjUaT7pbfEEwizOagAGYOQAWEtl5Tb3t74j1hOu5Pnj+dt8qH7Qdx1Nc1TDHG1J2nJ130vA9l1XZR2FIHoAEIX1gSIoEpF0m2QP9LyCWkLmWOAe3MMxyCoEABBKBIQTgEFsNwxtfwwVs01rYiVCAA)

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't considered using generics but I quite like the ergonomics of this solution!

Answer (score 0):

As defined now, `Token#type` can vary at runtime, so there is no way to make compile-time assertions about what kind of token types are used in what places. Your options include:

1. Switch to making runtime checks. For example, when a `FunctionDeclaration` is constructed (or, if it's a plain object, whenever it's accepted by a method), check the type of its `ident` token at runtime.
2. Make `Token` an `abstract` class and `type` an `abstract readonly` field. Then create subclasses for each token type (`class IdentifierToken`, `class FloatToken`, etc.) that fix it to a certain value (`readonly type = TokenType.Identifier`, `readonly type = TokenType.Float`, etc.). Note that this is different from a non-readonly field that can be freely assigned in a constructor argument. Having these subclasses might also help later when you need to input/output parsed data of the actual type (`number` for `Integer` and `Float`, for example).
3. If you're going to have subclasses anyway, perhaps question whether you need the `type` field at all. That kind of field can still have its uses within a class hierarchy, but keep in mind that you now also have `instanceof` checks available, not to mention simply overriding behavior in each subclass.

So yes, in the long run making those ~25 classes (preferably real classes rather than just interfaces) is going to be much cleaner. If you have that many token types, and different types need to behave differently in certain contexts, that's simply the necessarily level of complexity for your code.